# How to SELECT from either Table A or Table B based on a Value without using If statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Example:

```
Declare @Division int = 1

IF @Division = 1 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM A 
END 
ELSE IF @Division = 2 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM B 
END
```

The thing is, I don't want to use `if statements`, as there's hundreds of `Divisions` to consider.

This is part of a larger query where it's joined onto other tables.

How do I do this?

Comment: Seems like a poorly designed db is the main problem here.

Comment: Yes but that's not constructive is it

Comment: You should merge all the tables and store the division number as additional column. In this case you can do `SELECT * FROM division_table WHERE division_number = @Division`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables have exactly the same columns, you could do a `UNION ALL`:

```
declare @Division int = 1

SELECT * FROM A WHERE @Division = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B WHERE @Division = 2
-- etc
```

Or if they don't have exactly the same columns, but it's possible to gather all the interesting columns from each, then a more extensive version might work:

```
SELECT COL1 as ID, COL2 as VALUE, COL3 as DESCR FROM A WHERE @Division = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL6 as ID, COL7 as VALUE, NULL as DESCR FROM B WHERE @Division = 2
-- etc
```

I'm not sure however how *efficient* all this will be, compared to your initial version that uses the `IF`.

You can also put all of it in a CTE for easy joining with other tables:

```
;WITH DivisionCTE (ID, VALUE, DESCR) AS
(
    SELECT COL1 as ID, COL2 as VALUE, COL3 as DESCR FROM A WHERE @Division = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COL6 as ID, COL7 as VALUE, NULL as DESCR FROM B WHERE @Division = 2
    -- etc
)
SELECT *
FROM       DivisionCTE x
INNER JOIN OtherTable  y ON x.ID = Y.ID
-- etc
```

Comment: Do you think that this would be more efficient than a view pooling it into a collated table with the division included?

Comment: No sorry, that would be something you would definitely need to investigate.

Comment: This is helpful in several ways so thanks for this, nice answer.

Comment: View turned out slightly more efficient & faster but used most of this within it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create view on all required table by Union

create view DivisionWiseData
as
begin
select *,1 AS Division from tabA
union 
select *,2 AS Division from tabB
and so on...

after that simply use
select * from dbo.DivisionWiseData where divisionid=@divisionid